# send() not reporting ENOTCONN when client has closed the connection (AS400)

Tags: c++, sockets, ibm-midrange

This is on an AS400 (IBM i, iSeries, et al).

I have a small Java program that I use to send test files to a server written in C++, which also runs on the IBM i.  In my Java program I am setting my timeout for a response to be 5, lets say.  In the server I am randomly sleeping for 0 to 10 seconds.  When the Java program times out, it throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException, closes the socket with .close() and exits.  The server program just goes ahead after its sleep and calls send().  Thing is, send() does not fail with -1 and give ENOTCONN.  Why?  Also inet_ntop() on the socket gives me the remote IP and port that connected to the server, as though the socket were still connected.  Scratching my head.

EDIT: After disappointment with poll(), I found select() will report an error with FD_ISSET() when setting the errors set.  In my case, select() returns 3, indicating that 3 conditions (read, write and error) are set for my one socket.  You can't find out what the error is, at least I don't know yet how to find out.

```
fd_set read_set, write_set, error_set;
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_ZERO(&write_set);
FD_ZERO(&error_set);
FD_SET(sock_fd, &read_set);
FD_SET(sock_fd, &write_set);
FD_SET(sock_fd, &error_set);
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 10;           // reset this on every new iteration.
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
int rc = select(sock_fd + 1, &read_set, &write_set, &error_set, &timeout);
CERR << "select() returned " << rc << endl;
if (rc >= 0) {
    if (FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_set)) {
        CERR << "ready to read" << endl;
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &write_set)) {
        CERR << "ready to write" << endl;
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &error_set)) {
        CERR << "has an error" << endl;
        CERR << "errno=" << errno << ", " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the server didn't get the proper connection close handshake. Grab a packet trace and make sure the server was told to close.

Comment: TCP or UDP sockets?

Comment: TCP socket in this case

Answer (score 2):

From *man send*:

> ENOTCONN
>
> The socket is not connected, and no target has been given.

In other words your expectations are incorrect. ENOTCONN is for the case when *you* haven't connected the *socket*. It doesn't have anything to do with the peer disconnecting. That case will eventually cause ECONNRESET, but not on the first such send, because of TCP buffering.

Working as designed.